# Getting values from nested dictionary [values are in nested form]

Tags: python, dictionary

I have following dictionary:-

```
dictionaty = {
    'specs': {
        'classq0': {'priority': 0, 'BwShare': '10%'}, 
        'classq1': {'priority': 1, 'BwShare': '30%'}, 
        'classq2': {'priority': 2, 'BwShare': '60%'}
    }
}
```

I need to access values of priority and BwShare for each class i.e I need output like following:-

```
prio_classq0 = 0

BwShare_classq0 = 10%

prio_classq1 = 1

BwShare_classq1 = 30%

prio_classq2 = 2

BwShare_classq2 = 60%
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: So what's the problem? `dict1['key1']['key2']['key3']`

Comment: I am not getting values. Instead getting following:-  <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f5e5637b4a0>
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f5e5637b900>

Comment: You're using a generator expression and not converting it to a list. Use `list(whatever you're writing)`

Comment: If you want something more concrete, add the code to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dictionary = {
    'specs': {
        'classq0': {'priority': 0, 'BwShare': '10%'}, 
        'classq1': {'priority': 1, 'BwShare': '30%'}, 
        'classq2': {'priority': 2, 'BwShare': '60%'}
    }
}

out_dictionary = {}
for outer_key, inner_dict in dictionary['specs'].items():
    for inner_key, value in inner_dict.items():
        if inner_key == "priority":
            inner_key = "prio"
        out_dictionary = {
            **out_dictionary, 
            f"{inner_key}_{outer_key}": value
        }

print(out_dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need output to be in exact same order:

```
for key, value in dictionaty['specs'].items():
    for key2, value2 in value.items():
        first = key2 if key2!='priority' else 'prio'
        print(first + '_'+ key + ' = ' + str(value2))
```